# SQL Server : concatenate columns and use that value for IN statement

Tags: sql-server

I have a query concatenating `FirstName` and `LastName`. After concatenation, I would like to be able to run an in statement against this value. Perhaps it is past my bedtime, but I can not figure out the way to write this properly.

Example query

```
SELECT 
    FirstName + ' ' + LastName AS fullName
FROM 
    [my].[dbo].[dbOfNames] 
WHERE
    fullName IN ('John Smith', 'Mike Apple', 'Bob Burger')
```

I am not sure what I am missing here. Is there a way to accomplish concatenation and then check that value against an in statement or am I approaching this wrong?

Comment: Quote your strings. `'John Smith'`

Comment: HAHA sorry yea my query has quoted strings

Comment: You could also have used the full expression on the left side of `IN`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first use a [CTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql) to project your concatenated full name, which will then allow further operations and filtering on the derived columns, without having to repeat the concatenation operation:

```
WITH cteFullName as 
(
    SELECT FirstName + ' ' + LastName as fullName 
    FROM [my].[dbo].[dbOfNames] 
)
SELECT fullName
  FROM cteFullName
  WHERE fullName IN ('John Smith', 'Mike Apple', 'Bob Burger');
```

Another alternative, not as flowing IMO, is to use a derived table:

```
SELECT fullName
  FROM 
  ( 
     SELECT FirstName + ' ' + LastName as fullName 
     FROM [my].[dbo].[dbOfNames] 
  ) AS derivedFullName
  WHERE fullName IN ('John Smith', 'Mike Apple', 'Bob Burger');
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need

```
SELECT FirstName + ' ' + LastName as fullName 
FROM [my].[dbo].[dbOfNames] where FirstName + ' ' + LastName
 in ('John Smith', 'Mike Apple', 'Bob Burger')
```

Comment: That was it. Very helpful!